# Difference between IDE and Platform and Framework?

Tags: frameworks, ide, platform

i want to know the Difference between the 3 words in the title .. with example if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDE** = Integrated Development Environment ~ a program that helps you develop new programms.
a.e: Eclipse, idea

**Platform** = probably you mean the underlying system like Unix or windows.
a.e: windows, max, ubuntu

**Framework** = Usually a frame of functions that help you develop quicker, setup quicker and so on.
a.e: spring, spring boot, ruby on rails